# NSIS GetOptions is throwing an error even though the option is present

Tags: command-line, installation, nsis

I'm am trying to run a test installer (.exe) generated by NSIS while providing command line arguments. I'm using [GetParameters](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/AppendixE.html#getparameters) and [GetOptions](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/AppendixE.html#getoptions).

My code:

```
FileOpen $0 "$InstDir\output.txt" w

${GetParameters} $R1
${GetOptions} $R1 "-pss" $R2
IfErrors 0 +3
  FileWrite $0 "Success"
  Goto done
  FileWrite $0 "Fail"
done:

FileClose $0
```

and the command used when running this:

`installer.exe -pss`

I keep getting `Fail` in the text file, but the option is in the command line string. What am I doing wrong?

I've tried using `/pss` instead of `-pss` and that still gives me an error. I have also ran the same code with a few revisions:

```
FileOpen $0 "$InstDir\output.txt" w

${GetParameters} $R1
${GetOptions} $R1 "-pss=" $R2 ;;revision
IfErrors 0 +3
  FileWrite $0 "Success = $R2" ;;revision
  Goto done
  FileWrite $0 "Fail = $R2" ;;revision
done:

FileClose $0
```

with the command `installer.exe -pss=true` used and the `true` is written to the file which means `$R1` is recieving a value but I'm still getting an error.

The big thing here is that I don't need any actual value, but instead just need to see if the -pss option is available.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong or where my misunderstanding is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first `IfErrors` parameter is the place to jump if the error flag is set and you are using `0` and that means no jump so your code is a bit confusing.

I would recommend that you don't use relative jumps like this, use a label or even better, use the LogicLib:

```
!include FileFunc.nsh
!include LogicLib.nsh

Section

${GetParameters} $R1
${GetOptions} $R1 "-pss" $R2
${IfNot} ${Errors}
    DetailPrint "-pss switch found"
${Else}
    DetailPrint "-pss switch NOT found"
${EndIf}

SectionEnd
```

Comment: That worked! Awesome man, thanks. I knew about LogicLib but I thought I would use IfError for practice. But I guess there isn't much point when there is much better ways to do it.

Comment: My misunderstanding was that when `IfError` showed no error, the first argument was done. Again, thanks man!